# Uniqueness Test on Dataframe column and cross reference with value in second column - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of ***daily*** license_type activations (either full or trial) as shown below. Basically, I am trying to see the **monthly count** of Trial to Full License conversions. I am trying to do this by taking into consideration the daily data and the user_email column.

```
        Date        User_Email      License_Type P.Letter Month  (conversions)
    0   2017-01-01  10431046623214402832 trial  d       2017-01     
    1   2017-07-09  246853380240772174   trial  b       2017-07 
    2   2017-07-07  13685844038024265672 trial  e       2017-07     
    3   2017-02-12  2475366081966194134  full   c       2017-02 
    4   2017-04-08  761179767639020420   full   g       2017-04
```

The logic I have is to iteratively check the User_Email column. If the User_Email value is a duplicate, then check license_type column. If value in license_type = 'full' return 1 in a new column called 'Conversions' else return 0 in 'conversion' column. This would be the amendment to the original dataframe above.

Then group 'Date' column by month and I should have a aggregate value of monthly conversions in 'Conversion' column? Should look something like below:

```
Date
2017-Apr    1
2017-Feb    2
2017-Jan    1
2017-Jul    0
2017-Mar    1
Name: Conversion
```

below was my trial at getting the desire output above

```
#attempt to create a new column Conversion and fill with 1 and 0 for if converted or not.
for values in df['User_email']:
   if value.is_unique:
       df['Conversion'] = 0 #because there is no chance to go from trial to Full
   else:
       if df['License_type'] = 'full': #check if license type is full
             df['Conversion'] = 1        #if full, I assume it was originally trial and now is full
                
        # Grouping daily data by month to get monthly total of conversions
   converted = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%b'))['Conversion'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data doesn't have the features you note you are looking for.  Rather than loop *(always a pandas anti-pattern)* have a simple function that operates row by row

1. for uniqueness test I'm getting a count of use of email address first and setting the number of times it occurs on each row
2. your logic I've transcribed in a slightly different way.

```
data = """        Date        User_Email      License_Type   P.Letter   Month
    0   2017-01-01  10431046623214402832  trial  d       2017-01     
    1   2017-07-09  246853380240772174   trial  b       2017-07 
    2   2017-07-07  13685844038024265672  trial  e       2017-07     
    3   2017-02-12  2475366081966194134  full   c       2017-02 
    3   2017-03-13  2475366081966194134  full   c       2017-03 
    3   2017-03-13  2475366081966194  full   c       2017-03 
    4   2017-04-08  761179767639020420   full   g       2017-04"""
a = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ",l) if t.strip()!=""]  for l in [re.sub("([0-9]?[ ])*(.*)", r"\2", l) for l in data.split("\n")]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.assign(
    emailc=df.groupby("User_Email")["User_Email"].transform("count"),
    Conversion=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 0 if r["emailc"]==1 or r["License_Type"]=="trial" else 1, axis=1)
).drop("emailc", axis=1)

df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%b'))['Conversion'].sum()
```

**output**

```
Date
2017-Apr    0
2017-Feb    1
2017-Jan    0
2017-Jul    0
2017-Mar    1
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback Rob. I tried to implement this approach but get a AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'.